# Resizing my /home partition from ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I currently have Ubuntu 13.10 installed, with a separate partition for / and for /home. The question I have is can I resize the /home partition from the Ubuntu installation or is it better to boot live usb?

Comment: It is worth mentioning if there are any other partitions on the drive or space. Because if not you would need to shrink the / partition which is a completely different kettle of fish.

Comment: Well it's not similar at all really, because it's pretty obvious it would be extremely difficult/dangerous to have a wheel changed whilst a car is moving, whereas the real root of my question is asking is it the root partition that holds the operating system files as if this were the case, it would be possible to safely resize the /home partition..

Comment: And this is supposed to be a share and learn type forum, comments like that are a benefit to nobody..

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is best to manage your partitions when running a live USB. You would then manage your partitions with gparted (graphical interface).

You likely have to first unmount the hard drive swap partition (you can unmount partitions from the gparted interface).

You may have to resize in steps depending on your layout.

make / smaller (put the free space adjacent to /home) -> apply changes -> make /home larger -> apply changes

If you are using LVM or extended partitions it may be mor ecomplicated.